# How to scan for Windows viruses on Linux servers?

Tags: linux, windows, centos, anti-virus, malware

I have a CentOS server storing files for windows users.

How do I scan for windows viruses in these files, and meanwhile prevent quarantine and other measures?

I do not want the files altered in any way, and would prefer if it can be done purely in command line with parsable results.

The antivirus we have a license for is Kaspersky Endpoint Security.
That is the preferred antivirus, but the question applies to Linux Anti-viruses in general.

Comment: Did you check out kapersky for linux ?

Comment: This is definitely possible since [VirusTotal](https://virustotal.com) does so, but I would also like to know how to do so.

Comment: Yes. Actually mentioned it in the question as the antivirus of choice. Do you know how to : 1. Run it from commandline 2. Prevent it from quarantining and 3. does it find windows viruses? 4. How to parse it's results in commandline? (for automation) if you have an accurate answer I am sure this is a common problem!

Comment: Do you setup your windows OS AV to scan network share ?

Comment: It's not a network share. It's a RedHat EL server with files stored on it(part of a product). 
Some relevant resources I've found so far: https://support.kaspersky.com/4320 https://support.kaspersky.com/4318 https://support.kaspersky.com/4322 https://support.kaspersky.com/4323 https://support.kaspersky.com/4326

Comment: https://docs.s.kaspersky-labs.com/english/kav8.0_linuxfs_installation_en.pdf  I looked into Norton and their Linux AV does scan for windows viruses - though it has a shaky reputation and compatibility issues .. I've seen some sites advertise using ESET and AVG

Comment: ./kav4fs-control --action Skip --scan-file <file-to-scan> with Kaspersky File Server Security for Linux - now just to test it for effectiveness with windows viruses :)

Comment: This is really the wrong approach to take, you need antivirus protection on the user pcs to prevent entry to the system and limit damage. By the time it has got onto network shares it is too late.

Comment: JamesRyan: this isn't for network shares. it's meant for cloud storage services ( Dropbox, box and the like ) - there are many SaaS services that could use simple, integrated virus scanning.

Comment: Just got a reply from Kaspersky support! their linux antivirus also scans for windows viruses.
https://support.kaspersky.com/4386 shows how installation goes - it just includes a simple installer packages. The command for scanning is /opt/kaspersky/kav4fs/bin/kav4fs-control --scan-file <file/folder to scan> , some log parsing is required to fetch results

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but if you are happy using ClamAV the following should work:

Install the ClamAV (enabling EPEL repo first):

```
yum install -y epel-release
yum install clamav
```

Via: https://www.clamav.net/documents/installing-clamav#rhel

Then you can update ClamAV:

```
/usr/bin/freshclam
```

Then scan:

```
/usr/bin/clamscan -r --infected /
```

`--infected (-i)`: Only print infected files.
`--recursive (-r)`: Scan directories recursively. All the subdirectories in the given directory will be scanned.

It's worth noting that by default `clamscan` does *not* remove files, you would have to manually set the switch: `--remove[=yes/no(*)]`

Via: https://linux.die.net/man/1/clamscan

Regarding scanning for windows signatures in linux I will refer you to this accepted answer on AskUbuntu: [Does ClamAV Scan Windows virus?](https://askubuntu.com/a/454656)

> In practice however, you will mainly use a virusscanner to protect your Windows partners. ClamAV does scan for Windows viruses as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. While this may be true, I rather doubt ClamAV is very effective against Windows threats - It's not one of the leading antiviruses.

Comment: You're probably right. I guess it was designed for mail scanning. Have you looked into setting up a windows client (VM or physical) and just using a commercial client?

Comment: **clamav** is part of CentOS. Every windows-threat that was detected SEP was confirmed by clamscan. So it should work.